# UpdatePanel only update from events

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

hello every one my problem goes like this
i have two updatepannels

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="new_word_panel_UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate >    
          <asp:Panel ID='new_word_panel' runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID='new_word_btn' runat="server" Text='give me a new word' Visible='false' OnClick='GenNewWord' />            
          </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>

 </asp:UpdatePanel>  
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
     <ContentTemplate > 
  <asp:Button ID='Button8' runat="server" Text='hide' OnClick='hidegive' />
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

the first updatepanel UpdateMode is set to Conditional so i can
update is content from the second updatepanel asp:Button ID='Button8' OnClick='hidegive'
event easily by using the Update() method.

this is the eventhandler:

```
protected void hidegive(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (new_word_btn.Visible == true)
            new_word_btn.Visible = false;
        else
            new_word_btn.Visible = true;


        **new_word_panel_UpdatePanel.Update();**
    }
```

my problem is that i cant update the first UpdatePanel from reguler method on my page 
although i am using the Update() method, i have try to update panel from this
method and nothing hapeens:

```
void PlayerWinEventHandler(object sender,Game.PlayerWinEventArgs e)
    {


        Session["score"] = int.Parse(Session["score"].ToString()) + 10;
        UpdateScore();


        if (new_word_btn.Visible == true)
            new_word_btn.Visible = false;
        else
            new_word_btn.Visible = true;

        new_word_btn.Text = "zibi";
        **new_word_panel_UpdatePanel.Update();**

    }
```

thanks for your help...

Comment: Who raises the event `PlayerWinEvent`? What control on the UI?

Comment: another update panel :

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="select_letters_UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode='Conditional'>

Comment: he raises this event after calling 3 DB methods

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Triggers in your first update panel.

```
  <Triggers>
                      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button8" EventName="Click"/>
                    </Triggers>
```